# ExecuteJavaScript failing with error "ReferenceError: OpenQA is not defined"

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to simulate right click event on an anchor tag via javascript executor. But getting an error "ReferenceError: OpenQA is not defined". 
I am not sure if this is a right way of calling JS function in the selenium script.

```
IWebElement folderAtag = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@title='folderA911536']"));          
 IJavaScriptExecutor js2 = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver);

      js2.ExecuteScript(
          "function contextMenuClick(element){" +

             "var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +

              "var RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE = 2; " +

              " evt.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true," +
              "  element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, " +
              " false, false, false, RIGHT_CLICK_BUTTON_CODE, null); " +

              " if (document.createEventObject){ " +

                 "    return element.fireEvent('onclick', evt) " +
                 "  } " +
               " };" +
           "contextMenuClick(" + folderAtag + ");"
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

for proper execution of js code I use stringBuilder. e.g. below:

```
public void jsClick(String key) throws IOException {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+propertyKeysLoader(key) +"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

by the way, right mouse click on the element I would resolve in that way:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@title='folderA911536']"));
new Actions(driver).contextClick(elem).perform();
```

Comment: Right click is not working using Action ContextClick. it is right clicking 4 levels up in the folder tree, that is really weird. So I am trying to find if there is another method that could work.